# Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://artifactory.hello.com/artifactory/gradle-4.4.1-all.zip

Tags: intellij-idea

When I click gradle import all or command line gradlew clean build.

I am getting following error in IntelliJ

Please let me know where I am missing to give the user credntials.

Comment: What IntelliJ IDEA version do you use? Similar issue was fixed in 2019.2.